# VB - EXE files in my Bin/Debug file are created with an old name on Debug

Tags: vb.net, debugging, exe, filenames, bin

When I first created my VB solution I named it something that I had to change later on and now everytime I debug it, I go to Project/bin/Debug folder and exe (*.vshot*, *.vshot.exe*, *.vshot.exe.manifest*) files are being created with the first name I chose

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Solution Explorer", right click on the Project name ("WindowsApplication"+number by default), and click on "Properties". In the new window, tab "Application", write the new name under "Assembly name". This is to change the name of the generated .exe; if you want to change further properties (for example: "Description" when you right click on the .exe), you would have to modify more parameters via, for example, "Assembly Information" (button below "Assembly name").